# how to refresh the word list and send keys to input field

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to make a typing test bot however there is problem the site displays only limited words at time so i cant scrape them all. so i have to make a while loop which sends words to the input field and then refreshes the text_list.

here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

words = []

url = "https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/finnish"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

class_name = "CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButton"
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)
element.click()

# Wait for words to load
time.sleep(2)

# Locate the input field
input_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "inputfield")
text = driver.find_element(By.ID, "words")
element_text = text.text
text_list = element_text.split()

print(text_list)

k=0

while k != 200:
    input_field.send_keys(text_list[k])
    input_field.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
    text = driver.find_element(By.ID, "words")
    element_text = text.text
    text_list = element_text.split()
    print(text_list)
    k=k+1
```

I tried many other things to make this work but none of them did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done more simple that you do.

```py
#preivous code
input_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "inputfield")
words_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[wordnr]')

for word in words_elements:
    input_field.send_keys(word.text)
    input_field.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
    print(word.text)
```

You can get word elements by selector `span[wordnr]`, simply loop through elements array and type each elements text.